# innodb delete table is full

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have problem witch delete records in innodb (table have somitem 100k rekords or 1mln records)
Innodb have file per table
I don't know why its happen.
Always I can delete some records, next i see "table is full" ... after few secods i can delete more records..

```
mysql> DELETE from xxxx WHERE id > 1413139758 AND id <= 1413819239 LIMIT 10000;
Query OK, 10000 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> DELETE from xxxx WHERE id > 1413139758 AND id <= 1413819239 LIMIT 10000;
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'xxxx' is full
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if you have file-per-table active, deleting rows causes the old versions of rows to be copied to the central tablespace `ibdata1`. Just in case you roll back the delete, or in case there are other transactions reading the database who need to see the rows you deleted to preserve their repeatable-read view of the database.

The reason it clears up after a few seconds is that InnoDB gradually purges these copies of obsolete rows, and makes space in ibdata1.

Normally ibdata1 can auto-extend if it needs to store more data in its rollback segment. Did you configure ibdata1 without the autoextend keyword?

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_file_path';
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                  |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Without the `autoextend` keyword, the ibdata1 file has a fixed size, and you can fill it up pretty easily when you delete a lot of rows.

See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table

Comment: Yes, autoextend is set:
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_file_path';
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                           |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:128M |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: But you also have a `max`, beyond which the ibdata1 file will not extend. That is, InnoDB created the initial tablespace at 10M, and allowed it to grow, but then it stopped growing at 128M. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16522/what-happens-when-innodb-hits-its-tablespace-autoextend-max